# Convert string to DateTime type with formatting

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this line of code in C#:

```cs
var shipDate = doc.Root.Element("ShipmentHeader")?.Element("ShipmentDate")?.Value;
```

If extract the value out of XML file and shipDate is '20230631'
I want to convert this to Datetime type with the value of 06/31/2023

I tried these but none are working, either error or not a correct value.

```cs
var date = DateTime.TryParseExact(shipDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", 
                                  cultureInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, 
                                  out DateTime parsedDate) 
                   ? parsedDate : DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(shipDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
```

Comment: You need to tell DateTime.ParseExact() the date format of the string you want to parse, not the format that you want it in. DateTime does not have a format.

Comment: If you look at the definition of `DateTime` it is stored as a value of an instant in time. You then apply a format for display purposes. If you look at this article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-datetime) it tells you how to go from string to date. The format is the string to be parsed. See the comment from David.

Comment: `"20230631"` very much does not match the format string `"MM/dd/yyyy"`.  Perhaps you meant `"yyyyMMdd"` instead?

Comment: `string result = DateTime.ParseExact(shipDate, "yyyyMMdd", default).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");` if you want to change date *representation*.

Comment: There is no such date `20230631` (June only has 30 days). No wonder you're getting errors!

Comment: DateTime only formats on input/output and doesn't store a string in any format

Answer (score 0):

If you have an integer representation of something, it is fastest to work with it in the integer realm. You can extract year, month, and day using division and modulus, and create a `DateTime` structure using [this constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-datetime-ctor(system-int32-system-int32-system-int32)), which accepts integers.

```
var dateString = "20230630";
int dateInteger = int.Parse(dateString);
var date = new DateTime
(
    year:  dateInteger/10000, 
    month: (dateInteger/100) % 100, 
    day:   dateInteger % 100
);

Console.WriteLine("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", date);
```

Output:

```
06/30/2023
```

Of course, it is much clearer just to write:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
If you hover and read the description it says "The format of string (in your case shipDate) representation must match the specified format exactly"

You are passing 20230631 and expecting MM/dd/yyyy. So please use yyyyMMdd and then further convert it to MM/dd/yyyy

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(shipDate, "yyyyMMdd", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        var shipDate = "20230630";
        int year, month, day;
        int.TryParse(shipDate.Substring(0,4), out year);
        int.TryParse(shipDate.Substring(4,2), out month);
        int.TryParse(shipDate.Substring(6,2), out day);
        var fixedDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
        Console.WriteLine("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", fixedDate);
    }
}
```